# FileOutputStream error: File not found

Tags: android, image, file, store, fileoutputstream

I know it should be a nonsense but I´m having some difficults to store a image in a custom folder. I know how to store them into the cache directory or in the camera folder, but I want to store them into a custom folder and I´m having an error. I´m using this code:

```
                File folder = new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + "/ExtremEye");
                folder.mkdirs();
                fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(folder, "FRAME_"+ nombre + ".png"));
```

But I´m getting this logcat:

> File not found: /DCIM/ExtremEye/FRAME_20131101_120104.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

It´s a simple question, I know, but I have been trying different ways and I didn´t succeed.

Thanks for help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the logcat seems that is trying to access `DCIM` in the root `/`, but it should be on the External storage. Try this way:

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + "/ExtremEye");
```